# libsodium.dll runtimes folder was not found

Tags: nuget-package, bamboo, libsodium, argon2-ffi, bamboo-artifacts

I'm using libsodium 0.10.0.0 package to implement password hashing.

After installing the nuget package the entries are created in package.config and project file as below:

```
 <Reference Include="Sodium, Version=0.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\libsodium-net.0.10.0\lib\Net40\Sodium.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
```

The following Error occur after the build:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Could not copy the file "C:\Projects\GIT\EP2\ep2-api.git\Applications\AMS\packages\runtimes\win-x86\native\libsodium.dll" because it was not found. Ace.Ams.Web
```

In order to fix the above error I'm manually adding the below configuration settings in csproj file but still it's not working, and then I tried to manually copy the "runtimes" folder from the libsodium package path to above path and it's working in my local build but my bamboo auto build fails.

```
<ItemGroup> 
    <None Include="runtimes\win7-x86\native\**\*">
      <PackagePath>runtimes/win7-x86/native/</PackagePath>
      <Pack>true</Pack>
    </None>
    <None Include="runtimes\win7-x64\native\**\*">
      <PackagePath>runtimes/win7-x64/native/</PackagePath>
      <Pack>true</Pack>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' != 'net461'">
    <None Include="runtimes\osx-x64\native\**\*">
      <PackagePath>runtimes/osx-x64/native/</PackagePath>
      <Pack>true</Pack>
    </None>
    <None Include="runtimes\linux-x64\native\**\*">
      <PackagePath>runtimes/linux-x64/native/</PackagePath>
      <Pack>true</Pack>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```